# Collation change on MS sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, collation

**Dear all,** Currently I am just researching how I could handle the change of the collation on the database.

> Somebody made an unusual decision to create accent sensitive database for global use... but I am on the way to handle this!

REASON: of changing the collation is that database contains data collected from different countries and as we all know some of cultures have their own letters.

With the respect for the customers, our organization would like to have Accent Insensitive database. That will allow users to request data from the server without any limitations using local characters.

As far as I have find out, there may be an option to drop constraints and etc. change collation and then just to bring everything back. In this case I am afraid if this would be enough to affect already existing data (columns).

Another way, I have found an article in [Collation change on 2005 and 2008 server](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/302405/The-Easy-way-of-changing-Collation-of-all-Database). However, this does not include the 2012 server.

Also I am taking the complexity of this example into consideration as well.

I believe that I am not in an easy phase. But I am hoping to get few advises what would be the best and safest way to handle this.

Thank you for your concerns and assistance.

> **UPDATE** let me add what architecture do we have: The complete system contains 4 databases and more than 1.000 tables in total. So my expectations is that not all of the possible ways may work in an optimal way.

Answer (score 0):

me too i had to deal with a similar issue because of a different reason: ancient databases with an old SQL collation installed ages ago on a SQL6.5 server that has been inplace upgraded for each version from sql 7 to sql 2005 and now should be updated to sql 2012.

why all these inplace upgrades? because the actual collation was the server collation and was so old that is not available during then install process of a recent version (2000+) of sql server...

i decided to drop all that old rubbish so i had to find a way that allowed me to move to a new installation with a windows collation.

i had to exclude the data migration (create a new database and import data) because of the lack of documentation and the huge number of customizations, triggers, hidden rules and so on.

the solution i used (the order matters):

- disable automatic statistics generation
- script the creation of all foreign keys and then drop them
- script unique and primary indexes and then drop them
- script all remaining indexes and then drop them
- script custom statistics and then drop them
- script `CHECK` and `DEFAULT` constraints and then drop them

now you can run the `ALTER` commands needed to change the collation of the columns and change the collation of the database itself.

when done repeat the above in reverse order to rebuild all the needed objects.
it happens that if the database is so old as is mine you may incur in something funny like [existing foreign key that references fields with different datatypes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106799/existing-foreign-key-that-references-fields-with-different-datatype-char8-and).

Answer (score 0):

Changing collation of all existing columns is a real pain. I suggest a side-by-side migration rather than alter each column individually.  Create a new database with the desired collation containing only empty tables.  Copy data from the old db to the new one using `INSERT...SELECT` (or the ETL tool of your choice), and then create constraints, indexes, and other database objects.

Consider upvoting the [Make it easy to change collation on a database](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/358320/make-it-easy-to-change-collation-on-a-database) SQL Server feature request.

Comment: Dan Guzman, I like your idea to create a new database and then migrate data in the way as you have described that. But does it not sound to difficult, then we have 4 databases and more than 1.000 tables in total? (some of the tables are used for ETL process and etc)

Comment: @AdviceMe, a lot of tables will certainly be more work.  I suggest generating the need T-SQL using the catalog views, accounting for cases where columns must be skipped (e.g. computed ones) and when `IDENTITY_INSERT ON` is needed to preserve `IDENTITY` values.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of complicated solutions on the internet for inplace collation changes but the simplest (and safest) way we have found is to script out the database, alter the script to create a new db with the collation set at the start and then import the data to the new database.

We achieve this using MS SQL Server 2012 Management Studio in the following way:

1. Script out all database objects with Tasks -> Generate Scripts -> Script entire Database and all Database objects
2. Alter the script with the following 2 changes and then run it to create a new database:

   a) Change DB name to MY-NEW-DB

   b) Under the CREATE DATABASE statement add: ALTER DATABASE [MY-NEW-DB] collate Latin1_General_CS_AS
3. If desired, use a tool like RG SQL Compare to compare the old and new database to verify all indexes, constraints, types etc were the same and collation on relevant columns only was changed.
4. Run Tasks->Import Data ensuring 'Enable Identity Insert' checked. All data transferred to the new case sensitive database correctly.
5. Run DBCC CHECKDB if you wish to check consistency

Comment: Just a clarification: I assume that in step 2(b) you are referring to the `USE [master]` found right near the end of the file? That line appears several times when I scripted.

Comment: I have always placed it near the top so that it is set before tables are created.